# lvalue required as left operand of assignment - Trying to run a oops code

Tags: oop

I am getting the following error please help

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
  
class Test
{
private:
  int x;
public:
  Test(int x = 0) { this->x = x; }
  void change(Test *t) { this = t; }
  void print() { cout << "x = " << x << endl; }
};
  
int main()
{
  Test obj(5);
  Test *ptr = new Test (10);
  obj.change(ptr);
  obj.print();
  return 0;
}
```

I am getting the error:-

```
prog.cpp: In member function ‘void Test::change(Test*)’:
prog.cpp:10:33: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
   10 |   void change(Test *t) { this = t; }
      |
```

I am not able to understand why I am getting this error. Please Help

Comment: you can't assign value to ```this```. What you will need to do is, create reference of type ```Test``` and assign like ```this->reference = t```

Comment: Cool got it. Thanks.